# How do i generate a textbox with price when vehicle model is selected from a combo box

Tags: vb.net

I'm really new to VB.Net programming and I have this problem with my Car Showroom Management Project.

I have a car details Microsoft access database where I have ID (Primary Key auto generated by access database) and its corresponding details like VehicleName, VehicleModel, Vehicle Color... price etc.

I have two combo boxes:

1. Vehicle Company Names
2. Vehicle Models of corresponding Company names

Now I have populated 1st combo box with Vehicle Company names like Audi, BMW ect.
I successfully got the code to display the Vehicle Model names in 2nd combobox when one of the company name is selected from the 1st combobox.

Now my problem is I have a Textbox and I want it to generate the price automatically when a Vehicle Model is selected from the 2nd Combo box! How do I do it in a simple way?

This is how I populated my second combo box upon first:

```
If ComboBoxCarCompany.SelectedItem = "Audi" Then
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Wilson\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Databases\Skodadb.accdb")
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    cn.Open()
    da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from AudiTable", cn)
    da.Fill(dt)

    ComboBoxCarModel.DataSource = dt
    ComboBoxCarModel.DisplayMember = "VehicleModel"
    ComboBoxCarModel.ValueMember = "ID"
    cn.Close()
End If
```

Comment: Probably almost the same way you did for the second dropdown update upond first dropdown change. You should try and come back with some code if you have any trouble...

Comment: `Help` requires some code that we can look at and figure out what advice to give.

Comment: But I'm not sure as if which model will the user select. For the first combo box it is sure that the user has to select from the mentioned companies only! And i have this other form module where user can add new vehicles to the database. Now the 2nd combo box keeps on populating when there are new entries. How do i get the corresponding model's price from the database.

Comment: Preload the data or go fetch it when the users selects a Model.

Comment: okay can anyone tell me if there is a way to get its ID when something is selected from the same row? For example: i want to get that rows ID when i select a Vehicle Model name. Can you give me an query example?